# Powrshell: Only classes in latest module can be loaded

Tags: powershell

Environment:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.1.0
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.1.0
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.18363
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

Code:

```
#testmodule1.psm1
Class TestClass1
{

}

#testmodule2.psm1
Class TestClass2
{

}
```

Then in command line:

```
PS C:\data\cwd> [testclass1]

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    TestClass1                               System.Object

PS C:\data\cwd> using module testmodule2
PS C:\data\cwd> [testclass2]

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    TestClass2                               System.Object

PS C:\data\cwd> [testclass1]
InvalidOperation: Unable to find type [testclass1].
```

It seems with the load of the 2nd module the classes in the first module was clear out from the memory
Can you please advise?

Comment: what happens if you issue the `using module testmodule1` after issuing `using module testmodule2`?

Comment: While counterintuitive (and slightly annoying), this is expected behavior. `using module ...` is designed to lift a module's type resolver into _script scope_ before type emission and execution - for this reason, they "reset" any previous imports because the assumption is that the statement runs _before_ anything else in the current scope has.

Comment: @Jeff Zeitlin then [testclass2] will be unloaded :(

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen hmm is there a way to save all the previous loaded class then reload?

Comment: No, but you can load as many module as you want by using [the answer provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66510582/712649) - I would suggest putting the `using module ...` statements in a single file (let's call it `imports.ps1`), then dot-source that (`. .\import.ps1`)from the console

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen thanks a million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this like a SINGLE command `using module '$SomePath\testmodule1.psm1'; using module '$SomePath\testmodule2.psm1'`

else directive Using module $SomePath\testmodule1.psm1 Replace to $SomePath\testmodule2.psm1

Comment: Amazing it did the magic. Can you please explain a bit more for the approach? Although in real life it could be a bit difficult to apply(giving there are multiple modules and I couldn't predict which ones are needed...

Comment: Combined with the information provided:  putting the using module ... statements in a single file (let's call it imports.ps1), then dot-source that (. .\import.ps1)from the console –